# Functional error handling. Execute all handlers

Tags: scala, error-handling, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have multiple values `F[A]` which may finish their evaluation with some error. There are some actions to be done in case an error occurred. How to execute handlers for ***all of the values***, not just the first at which an error occurred?

For example

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect._

class Test[F[_]: Sync] {

  def executeAllHandlers[A, B, C](fa: F[A], fb: F[B], fc: F[C]): F[(A, B, C)] =
    for {
      a <- fa
      b <- fb
      c <- fc
    } yield (a, b, c)
}

object Test extends App{
  val ioa: IO[Int] = IO.raiseError(new Error) onError {
    case _ => IO(println("ioa"))
  }

  val iob: IO[String] = IO.raiseError(new Error) onError {
    case _ => IO(println("iob"))
  }

  val ioc: IO[Double] = 2.5.pure[IO]

  //prints ioa and fails with Error
  new Test[IO].executeAllHandlers(ioa, iob, ioc).unsafeRunSync() 
}
```

The thing that I want to achieve is to execute handlers for all faulty evaluations which in the case above are `ioa` and `iob` and fails with an error (does not matter which one).

Is it possible to achieve something like this in cats? Maybe `mtl` typeclasses can be helpful here?

Comment: `IO` shortcircuits is `flatMap` on failure.You would need to track your errros explicitly, something like `IO[Either[Error, A]` and then combine all its errors, maybe using **Validated** or the parallel typeclasses.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Looks like a way to go. `IO` can be `attempt`ed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a hint given by `@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez` here is how the function can be modified so all handlers are executed

```
def executeAllHandlers[A, B, C](fa: F[A], fb: F[B], fc: F[C]): F[(A, B, C)]=
(for {
  a <- fa.attempt
  b <- fb.attempt
  c <- fc.attempt
} yield for {
  a <- a
  b <- b
  c <- c
} yield (a, b, c)).flatMap(Sync[F].fromEither)
```

Now it executed both of the handler and then throws `Error`.

```
ioa
iob
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this could be simplified or made more general than just three operations. You may get better luck in the **cats-effect** gitter channel: https://gitter.im/typelevel/cats-effect